Websocket stomp https issue using Spring MVC
`function connect() {
console.log('Here is the nick name: ', nickname);
console.log('Here is the full name: ', fullname);
document.getElementById('messengerinitiateGroupCreation').addEventListener('click', initiateGroupCreation);
document.getElementById('messengercreateGroup').addEventListener('click', createGroup);
document.getElementById('messengercloseDialog').addEventListener('click', closeGroupCreationDialog);
if ((nickname === "null" || nickname === 'undefined' || nickname === null) && (fullname === 'null' || fullname === 'undefined' || fullname === null)) {
    const nickname = null;
    const fullname = null;
    console.log("if")
    stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
}else {
    const socket = new SockJS('/EAZee/ws');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
}

}`
Here is my chat.js code
    @Override public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) { registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS(); }
Here is my WebSocketConfig.java Code
   @Override public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) { registry.addMapping("/**") .allowedOrigins("https://eaxee.com", "http://eaxee.com:8080", "http://localhost:8080/EAZee/")        .allowedMethods("*") .allowedHeaders("*") .allowCredentials(true); }
Here is my SpringMvcConfig.java Code
I also set the Proxy values
# Proxying WebSocket requests
ProxyPass /EAZee/ws wss://localhost:8080/EAZee/ws
ProxyPassReverse /EAZee/ws wss://localhost:8080/EAZee/ws
Firstly I am new at Web Scoket. It is working fine on http but when I use https then connection not estaablished.
